# samsung galaxy s duos s7562 update is not installing

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s

I have Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562 and recently received a notification about Software Update so that i proceed to install but update is not installing my mobile.

I tried using Kies also and getting the same result.

Note: I rooted my mobile and i disabled few services.

so i need to know, Is there any service should be running to install updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, official over-the-air (OTA) updates from Google/carriers/manufacturers will not install on rooted devices, especially if you've changed something on the /system partition.  The update usually checks if the device is in a given state, and won't proceed with installation if it detects tampering.

If you want to accept the OTA update, you will first need to bring the phone back to its original state.  This means undoing whatever modifications you performed, and un-rooting it.  After updating you should be able to re-root.